# Derivative of a scalar-valued function of a matrix

Tags: calculus, matrices, matrix-calculus

Consider a scalar-valued function of a Matrix:
$$s = g(\mathbf{T})$$ where $\mathbf{T}$ is a matrix.
Now consider $\mathbf{T}$ is also a function of a scalar variable $t$:
$$s = g(\mathbf{T}(t))$$
The goal is to find the derivative of $s$ with respect to $t$.
I approached this problem using the chain rule:
$$\dot s=\frac{\partial g}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial g}{\partial \mathbf{T}}\cdot\frac{\partial \mathbf{T}}{\partial t}$$
The problem is, the above expression results in a matrix, whereas I am expecting a scalar. Where am I wrong?

Comment: Because you can't divide a scalar by a matrix.

Comment: @Allawonder But you can get the derivative.

Comment: @Allawonder Derivative of a scalar with respect to a matrix is [well-defined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Scalar-by-matrix).

Comment: @J.G. Yes, but not by dividing by a matrix, as OP has done.

Comment: @MohammadJavadTaheri Yes, the various differentials are well-defined. What I said was that their quotient has no well-known meaning.

Comment: @Allawonder I see no quotient. Which expression is that?

Comment: @J.G. Look at the first factor on RHS of last equation in OP.

Comment: @Allawonder You mean $\frac{\partial g}{\partial T}$? That's a ratio of what, exactly?

Comment: @Allawonder [Let's stay calm](https://meta.stackexchange.com/conduct). A partial derivative of a scalar with respect to a matrix is not a scalar-to-matrix quotient.

Comment: @J.G. I'm calmer than you imagine. So exactly what does that notation signify?

Comment: The matrix whose ${}_{ij}$ entry is $\frac{\partial g}{\partial T_{ij}}$, as per @MohammadJavadTaheri's link. Unfortunately, you characterized $\frac{\partial g}{\partial T}$ as the quotient of the $\frac{\partial g}{\partial T_{ij}}$, which it isn't.

Comment: @J.G. No, that's not what I meant, but not to worry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The chain rule here is$$\frac{ds}{dt}=\frac{\partial s}{\partial T_{ij}}\frac{dT_{ij}}{dt}.$$While both factors are matrices, your mistake was thinking they're "dotted" in a way that forms a matrix, e.g. by matrix multiplication. But as we contract both indices, [it's really](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_inner_product) a quantity of the form $\operatorname{Tr}(A^TB)$.

Comment: Thanks, I understood my mistake. Meanwhile, for a better clarification, I suggest using summation sign for the chain rule.

Comment: @MohammadJavadTaheri [No need](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation).

Answer (score 0):

Well what you have is that $$\frac{\mathrm ds}{\mathrm dt}=\vec{\frac{\partial s}{\partial T_{ij}}}\cdot\vec{\frac{\mathrm dT_{ij}}{\mathrm dt}}.$$